# Facebook Feed dialogs Problem

Tags: facebook, api, dialog

I'm working on adding Facebook dialog to my site I got the code from the developers pages . created an application on facebook and tried it with the example app-id It works but when I change the app-id to my app-id It doesn't work and I got the following error:

"Error with , try again later"

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application needs to be running on the same url that is specified in the settings for your application.  I normally setup a host file entry for local testing.